# referencing sheets by number instead of name in cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Lets say 
`sheet3.name = "d"`

Is there a way I could put in a cell on `sheet2` the formula `=sum(sheet3!b:b)` where `sheet3` is being substituted with the actual sheet3 name?

I can only get `=sum('d'!b:b)` to work so far.

I could use VBA for this probably but I'm curious how to do this in a cell so I don't have to run a macro each time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can use a UDF *User Defined Function* that will return the sheet name

```
Function SHEETNAME(number As Long) As String
    SHEETNAME = Sheets(number).Name
End Function
```

then a formula like

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(SHEETNAME(3) &"!B:B"))
```

will return the sum from column B on sheet 3.

`SHEETNAME(number)` returns the sheet name of the number which is index.

So `Sheet(1)` returns Sheet1, etc

Comment: @user2872180, please keep in mind that this will not work if you change sheets order by moving sheet(3) to new position or adding new sheet before sheet(3). In such situation the only solution is the one I proposed.

Comment: SHEET(number) does _not_ return the sheet name for the number provided. [excel reference](http://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-sheet-function.html)

Comment: @martinp999 The above function called `SHEET` will return the name of the sheet.  `Sheet = Sheets(number).Name`

Comment: I suggest you both look up the help on this and do a test for yourself.  From the help "Returns the sheet *number* of the reference sheet.", a quick test shows this to be correct.

Comment: @martinp999 i think youre misunderstanding the point here. The above function which I now renamed to SHEETNAME, return the sheet name based on the number you send in as the parameter. This has nothing to do with the [built-in `SHEET()` function](http://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-sheet-function.html) you're referencing. It's just a coincidence the above function was ogiginally named `Sheet`.

Comment: Be sure to paste the code into a regular code module, not a Workbook, Worksheet or Class module.

Answer (score 7):

Use below formula anywhere in the sheet to get the sheet name - the sheet **must** have a filename for this to work:

```
=REPLACE(CELL("filename"),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename")),"")
```

You can either reference that cell using Indirect:

```
=SUM(Indirect("'"&A1&"'!B:B"))
```

or, if you don't want to have a second cell, you can combine the two formulas into one:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&REPLACE(CELL("filename"),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename")),"")&"'!B:B"))
```

Comment: This returns the name of the sheet where the formula is located.  The OP asked for a way to reference a sheet based on it's indexed location within the workbook.  The UDF posted by user2140173 handles this nicely.  The answer by @edata also accomplishes this.

Comment: this returns the name of the active sheet at the last calculation of values, not the sheet where the cell is located. Its only really an option if your workbook has just one sheet, otherwise you will get unexpected results

Answer (score 2):

For anyone not concerned with the order of the sheets, the post by Biff [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/639508-can-formulas-look-up-sheet-numbers-instead-sheet-names-post3174560.html#post3174560) on mrexcel.com works well.

In Excel 2013, go to the Formulas tab in the ribbon and make a defined name:

```
Name: SheetNames
Refers to: =GET.WORKBOOK(1)&T(NOW())
```

Then use a formula like this example:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(MID(SheetNames,FIND("]",SheetNames)+1,255),A3)&"'!A1")
```

where A3 refers to the index number in a cell in the current sheet, and A1 refers to the location of the value to be retrieved from the other sheet.  I.e., in the current sheet, if A3 = 2, then the formula will point to cell A1 in the second sheet of the workbook.  I just use a column of index numbers in my current sheet, then drag this formula down and it fills in values from all of my other sheets.

You will need to save as a macro-enabled file (.xlsm).

Comment: This is far more useful if it's an option, in my opinion.  Since the defined name can be associated and moved with the sheet (unlike a UDF which is workbook specific and cannot move with a sheet), creating a sheet that contains a set of formulas that indirectly reference ranges in an unknown number of other sheets, then moving that sheet to any other workbook so that your formulas can compile data from however many sheets happen to exist in that workbook becomes a possibility that is otherwise unavailable without VBA.  edata, your solution is excellent; thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea but it's the first one I could think of.

I would add additional function to your VBA project which will return actual name of your Sheet3:

```
Function Sheet3Name()
    Sheet3Name = Sheet3.Name
End Function
```

Next, when you create sum formula of column B:B in Excel cell you need to do it in this way:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(Sheet3Name()&"!A:A"))
```