# Referring to dynamic worksheets names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there any way I can use Sheets `INDEX` instead of `NAME` to address it?
For example I have
`Sheet1 (Calculations)`
How can I address this sheet instead of using:
`='Calculations'!CELL`
    I need it as sheets names will be changing according to their values

Comment: If i have in sheet1 `=Sheet2!A1` and rename *Sheet2* to *Sheet5* then also the formula changes to `=Sheet5!A1`. there should be no problem... but insertig a sheet or changing the order would mess up your sheetindex way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link provides a way to do it with a user-defined function in VBA:
[referencing sheets by number instead of name in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790985/referencing-sheets-by-number-instead-of-name-in-cells)

However, you may also want to consider a method that does not change the sheet names. As @DirkReichel implies, you can change sheet indices without changing sheet names and vice versa.

You might try using summary information stored on the sheet in question or keeping a summary sheet that references each sheet.