# sumifs to loop all sheets

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

Regardless of cell references, how would I make a sumifs formula reference across multiple sheets in VBA?

This is being built into a template and there would be a different number of sheets with different names each time it is run so I would be not be able to reference the sheets.

Comment: You could use `Sheets(1)` or whatever the sheet number reference is in your workbook. There are a lot of things you could potentially do, but hard to say without more information.

Comment: View the answer to this question for an idea of how to reference sheets by number within a formula: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790985/referencing-sheets-by-number-instead-of-name-in-cells

Comment: i would basicly need in my summary sheet in cell B3 to do a sumifs(B2006:B3005(over all sheets), where summaryA3 =  all sheets A2006:A3005 and summary B2 = all sheets B2005)

Comment: Thanks David, I dont think I can use this as the workbook could have 3 sheets or 300 sheets, this is unknown un till the first macro is run so cant reference sheet numbers, also if it is run once, then again, it creates new sheets and deletes the old ones which shifts on the sheet numbers, thatsthe main reason I need a loop for all sheets in the workbook!

Comment: Google "3d SUMIFS".  It will show how to use a formula for this.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner for suggestion, I have the folowing but its errors on the formular, any Ideas?

Comment: Sheets("Summary").Range("AI3:AI150").Name = "Invoices"

Range("B3").formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(" '"&Invoices&"'!"&"A2006:A3005"),A3,INDIRECT("'"&Invoices&"'!"&"B2006:B3005")))"

Comment: Does the formula work if you enter it directly to the sheet?  Make it work in the sheet first then record a macro pasting the formula in a cell, Excel will then create the proper form for vba.

Comment: Try this formula `"=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'"" & Invoices & ""'!B2006:B3005""),A3))"`

Comment: its not working on the sheet, its reconising that its a formula and reconising my list but brings up #Ref

Comment: I think its close but its still not quite there

Comment: Then there is a misspelling in one or more of the sheet names in the Invoices range.  Make sure that they are spelled exactly the same and there are no spaces that are not in both.

Comment: TOP Man the range was selecting a blank cell so would crash out

Comment: Now write an answer telling us what you did for future searches.  then in two days, if no one else comes up with a better method, mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it was done in full:

My original formula was

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(" '"&Invoices&"'!"&"A2006:A3005"),A3,INDIRECT("'"&Invoices&"'!"&"B2006:B3005")))"
```

this worked when putting straight into a cell but as you can see, when adding it to VBA it reads it as a comment. To fix this, every time you use a `"` you need to add extra `"` as shown below (apart from before the `"=` at the start and after the `)"` at the end of the formula).

```
 *****'list all the sheet names in cell AI1 of the sheet summary*****
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Sheets("Summary").Range("AI1")(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
***'clear the first 3 entries in AI as i didnt need the first three sheet names***
Sheets("Summary").Select
Sheets("Summary").Range("AI1:AI3").Clear
***'select the first sheet name, which is in AI4 as we cleard the first 3 to the last used cell, e.g Ctrl.Shift.down*** 
Sheets("Summary").Activate
Sheets("summary").Range(ActiveSheet.Range("AI4"),    ActiveSheet.Range("AI4").End(xlDown)).Select
***' Name the range invoices***
Selection.Name = "Invoices"
' ***Formula to do a sumIf looping all the shets in the named range Invoices***
Sheets("summary").Range("B3").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!$A$2006:$A$3005""),$A3,INDIRECT(""'""&Invoices&""'!B$2006:B$3005"")))"
```